# Ubuntu 12.04 + Mono: cannot find Windows forms

Tags: winforms, mono, ubuntu-12.04

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I need to run a Mono environment application (which needs Windows forms).
I have installed Mono runtime, from [badgerports.org](http://badgerports.org), version: `mono-runtime 3.2.8+dfsg-4~dhx1+precise1.`

When I go:

```
mono Application.exe
```

it bumps with:

`Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.`

I have then installed:

```
libmono-winforms2.0-cil 3.2.8+dfsg-4~dhx1+precise1
```

But when running again:

```
 mono Application.exe
```

I am getting the same error message as before:

`Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.`

Help will be appreciated

Many thanks in advance

Helen

---

Edit: should I find where the library has been downloaded (how)? and then install it into Mono GAC using gacutil (How??)